# Which directories to import to work with Xml and Linq - C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Could someone point out to me which directory I should be using to work with keywords such as 'From' 'select' and 'where' for LINQ?

I'm trying to do this:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(workingDir + @"\Moduleslist.xml");
var items = From d in document.Descendants("Name")
                        select d.Value;
```

But its giving me errors on 'From' and 'select' 'Value' and 'Descendants'. I've tried importing System.Xml.Linq; and System.Linq; but none allow me to use these keywords. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: They are called namespaces, not directories. Using the right words helps in Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `from` instead of `From`

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I still can't access the XDocument methods Load and Descendants even when I have System.Xml.Linq.XDocument; imported.

Comment: @AZ1, You have to add `System.Linq` and `System.Xml.Linq` namespaces. Also add references to `System.Xml` and `System.Xml.Linq` assemblies.

Comment: I have them both but still not recognizing the methods

Answer (score 1):

use System.Linq for LINQ and Linq keywords are in small case like from, select etc

[LINQ Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx)